# How to get date from datepicker in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In header file I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)displayDay:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
- (IBAction)displayDay:(id)sender {

    NSDate *chosen = [UIDatePicker date];

}
```

Xcode is telling me I should have UIdatePicker, but when I make that change it says "No know class method for selector 'date'".

Any advice on how to deal with this?

Comment: Please paste the datepicker code

Comment: How did you create the date picker ? Please paste that code

Comment: Simply calling [date Picker date] will not work. We need to allocate and initialize the date picker and pick the date from it.

Comment: date is an getter i.e, an instance method not class method.

Comment: self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init use the above in the viewdidload should help you

Comment: @IOSDEV: why are you allocating an IBOutlet ???

Comment: NSDate *chosen = [UIDatePicker date]; in te place of UIDatePicker give  your picker name.

Answer (score 13):

The following code won't work:

```
NSDate *chosen = [UIDatePicker date];
```

Because the `date` is not a class method it's a property of [**UIDatePicker**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) class.

> **date**
>
> The date displayed by the date picker.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The default is the date when the UIDatePicker object is created. The
>   date is ignored in the mode UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer; for that
>   mode, the date picker starts at 0:00. Setting this property does not
>   animate the date picker by spinning the wheels to the new date and
>   time; to do that you must use the setDate:animated: method.

You need to use it like:

```
NSDate *chosen = [datePicker date];
```

Comment: Thanks! When I do this though, Xcode is telling me I should have UIdatePicker...it gives me an error that I can't seem to ignore.

Comment: just try with `_datePicker`

Comment: @sharataka: what is the error ? you got when used datePicker and _datePicker ?

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
- (IBAction)displayDay:(id)sender 
{

  NSDate *chosen = [self.datePicker date];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)displayDay:(id)sender {

    NSDate *chosen = [yourdatepicker date];
      NSLog(@"%@",chosen);
}
```

try like this.